# shrink ext4 partition on raid 10

Tags: partitioning, raid, ext4

My question is similar to [Move ext4 partition](https://askubuntu.com/questions/147132/move-ext4-partition), but the challenge I couldn't figure out is how to shrink a partition from the start.

So suppose originally the partition (with raid) is like this.

```
(************** /dev/md127 ***************)
```

After resizing, I want to achieve like this.

```
(*** unallocated ***)(**** /dev/md127 ****)
```

Note, I cannot use gparted, and parted does not support ext4.

The commands I have tried so far,

```
% resize2fs -p /dev/md127 1676G    # <== This is good.

% lvreduce -L 1676G /dev/md127
Path required for Logical Volume "md127"
Please provide a volume group name
Run `lvreduce --help' for more information.
```

Then I found some link (http://www.howtoforge.com/how-to-resize-raid-partitions-shrink-and-grow-software-raid) that describing how to change partition of raid.

```
$ mdadm --grow /dev/md127 --size=max
mdadm: Cannot set device size for /dev/md127: Invalid argument
```

Failed here, "man mdadm" shows that "--grow" does not with raid 10. Need some help. Note, I use "--size=max" just for quick test, it won't work with other values either.

Then after that, I am thinking to create another partition right after this one, copy the data to that partition, and remove this one, like.

```
1. (************** /dev/md127 ***************)

2. (**** /dev/md127 ****)(*** new partition **)

3. (*** unallocated ****)(**** /dev/md127 ****)
```

Thanks.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to resize / enlarge / grow a non-LVM ext4 partition](http://askubuntu.com/questions/115310/how-to-resize-enlarge-grow-a-non-lvm-ext4-partition)

Comment: Question modified, definitely not duplicate.

Comment: After some searching, I finally realize it is not possible to --grow RAID 10.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have some confusion in your question that needs cleared up first, but it looks like the answer is that you can not do what you want.

First, `lvresize` is for changing the size of an lvm logical volume, so is not applicable to `/dev/md127` because that is a raid array.  Second, you asked to have unallocated space preceeding `/dev/md127`, which does not make sense because it is a raid array, so there is no space before or after it, in terms of the raid array.  The raid may be built on top of partitions, like `/dev/sda1` and `/dev/sdb1`, so *that* must be where you want preceding free space.  `mdadm` can change the size of `/dev/sda1` that is used for the raid, allowing you to use `parted` to shrink that partition, but that only moves the end of the array and partition, not the start.  There is no way to move the start.