# How to install Windows 10?

Tags: dual-boot, partitioning, windows

I was trying to install Windows 10 .[Windows Installer Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hmI9H.jpg). I have ubuntu 20.04 at present.It  has partitions 512.0 MB and 931.0 GB [GParted Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oOwpw.jpg). How to solve my problem.How can I get an extra partition where I will install Windows 10.

Comment: [This answer from a few years ago](https://askubuntu.com/a/564071/1222991) is still valid today 

Comment: Both Windows & Linux systems install in the same mode UEFI or BIOS as you boot install media. You have UEFI system and gpt partitioned drive. So Windows will only install in UEFI boot mode. Use gparted to shrink the Linux partition to make unallocated space for Windows. BIOS & UEFI Windows partitions, note system has totally different format  & meaning between BIOS & UEFI
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/hardware/dn898510%28v=vs.85%29.aspx#RecommendedPartitionConfigurations & 
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/hardware/dn898504%28v=vs.85%29.aspx

Comment: Booting from Live Ubuntu USB open GParted. Right click Ubuntu ext4 partition and select Unmount. Right click again and select Resize/Move. Stretch partition to left and click Resize/Move at bottom right. click green check mark to Apply All Operations. Windows should be more cooperative installing in Legacy mode. After installing Windows you will need to reinstall GRUB to boot Ubuntu: `sudo mount /dev/sdxy /mnt` then `sudo grub-install --boot-directory=/mnt/boot /dev/sdx` where sdxy is the Ubuntu partition and sdx is the Ubuntu drive.