# Go to LVM with an already non-LVM disk, how to?

Tags: partitioning, system-installation, lvm, clone, cloning

I plan to use LVM. My Ubuntu is currently non-LVM based.

I wonder if I can do that without resintalling or 
if I can:

- resize current partition (call it part Old)
- create new partition (call it part LVM)
- clone part OLD files to part LVM files
- delete part old

And finally have the same Ubuntu LVM-based.

Is this naive vision possible ?
If not, which is the normal way ?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you can. You can even put your swap space and `/boot` files on the LVM so you will have two logical volumes: one for the swap space and the other for `/`.

Comment: Thanks. But is it possible to change partition size of a non-LVM lv ?

Comment: If you mean changing the size of a partition, you can do it with the `gparted` tool. This question has been answered here: http://askubuntu.com/questions/115310/how-to-resize-enlarge-grow-a-non-lvm-ext4-partition?rq=1

Comment: I've done what you suggest, so I can verify that it's possible; however, I recommend keeping `/boot` on a real partition, not inside an LVM. Although GRUB is *supposed* to be able to read files off an LVM, I've never tested this, and I know of no distribution that attempts such a setup; they all use separate `/boot` partitions when an LVM is used. Thus, `/boot` inside an LVM is, at best, non-standard and poorly tested. It definitely will *not* work with some non-GRUB boot loaders.

Comment: If the OP could post some information on the existing filesystems and partition including the output of df. Rod Smith - I have several systems reading /boot from an LVM, it somewhat complicates getting GRUB installed but once that is overcome it works fine. It is more complicated using a gpt partition table.