# How do you get a raid with 4 terabytes to give you the full disk amount in ubuntu server

Tags: server, partitioning, mount, hard-drive, raid

I am running Ubuntu server 14.  I have two 2 Terabyte Seagate drives raided to make a 4 terabytes.  However when I mount the logical drive and run `sudo lshw -c disk` it shows as having 3999 GB of room.  However when I run `df` command it shows only 2113 gb.  I used ext4 when formatting it.  I followed [this guide](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/InstallingANewHardDrive)
to add my drives.

Comment: Which RAID level did you use?

Comment: [link](http://example.com) _italic_ **bold** `code`Raid 0

Comment: Software RAID or Hadware RAID? If hardware RAID, what is the hardware vendor and type?

Comment: hardware, I am using a 3ware 9xxx card bios

Comment: can you query the hardware about the RAID level and RAID member capacity? Do you have LVM? Have you check in fdisk if all sectors already allocated?

Comment: im new to linux, do you mind giving me the command lines to do so?  Ill repost the results here

Comment: im not familiar with 3ware so i dont really know the interface for query the hardware. Eg like HP SmartArray we can use `hpacucli` utils. However we can check the `fdisk`. Can you add in your question output of `fdisk -l`?

Comment: Disk /dev/sdc: 4000.0 GB, 3999977701376 bytes
90 heads, 3 sectors/track, 28935023 cylinders, total 7812456448 sectors
Units = sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
Disk identifier: 0x2c960c55
Device Boot Start End Blocks Id System
/dev/sdc1 2048 4294967294 2147482623+ 83 Linux

Comment: Looks like the partition only use half of the capacity. Please look into my answer how to extend your partition.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you have something else configured than raid0. Looks a bit like raid1 cause 2113gb/1024=2,06TB wich might be because of some spare sectors.

If you want to have full size you would need raid0 (stripe), that gives you maximum speed and no extra data safety.

[Raid-Levels on Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Standard_RAID_levels)

After verifying the correct Raid Type we need to check on the device and how the system sees it.

In your case we have a hardware controller that normally gives raid-arrays as normal drives to the system. I.e. /dev/sdc /dev/sdd etc.

use: `sudo lshw -c disk` to see the devices Ubuntu sees.

In your case we see that the raid is presented as  /dev/sdc

If you have the desktop envirement setup you could simply use [gparted](http://gparted.sourceforge.net/) (`sudo apt-get install gparted`). That looks simply like the diskmanager in Windows and is quite selfexplaining.

If you do not have the desktop set up and running a terminal mode server use `sudo fdisk /dev/sdc` to enter the terminal partitioning tool.

If you have not setup a LVM this will be the guide to follow: [How to resize / enlarge / grow a non-LVM ext4 partition](https://askubuntu.com/questions/115310/how-to-resize-enlarge-grow-a-non-lvm-ext4-partition)
Just replace the /dev/??? with your /dev/sdc to match it your configuration.

**!!! PLEASE ALWAYS NOTE THAT CHANGES TO THE PARTITIONTABLE WILL/MIGHT RESULT IN A COMPLETE LOSS OF DATA ON THAT DRIVE !!!
BACKUP EVERYTHING FIRST!**

Hope this will do the trick for you.

Comment: yes i used raid 0 due to needing the size and not the redundancy.

Comment: Do you use a hardware raid controller or software or fake-raid of bios feature over normal dual chnnel sata?

Comment: Does 

cat /proc/mdstat

gives any hints on your configuration?

Comment: i have not looked yet would i use nano to view?

Comment: I am using hardware by 3ware.

Comment: Just in terminal type "sudo cat /proc/mdstat"
But I guess that the hardware raid will show the raid as /dev/sda or sdb or similar. Then it wont be in mdstat but that will be displayed at "sudo lshw -c disk" where you found your first data about the disk.
BTW afaik inside lshw you will be presented the raw data of the device (/dev/sda). In df you will be shown the configured partitionsizes (/dev/sda1 etc.).
so maybe you should look in gparted (if GTK envirement is presendt) or fdisk or gdisk and check if the partition inside the disk is the full size or just a part of it.

Comment: i ran sudo cat /proc/mdstat and it came back saying unused devices: <none>

Comment: So ithink the raid controller gives the raid to ubuntu as /dev/sda or /dev/sdb or something.  So do a "sudo fdisk -l" and check if there is your disk that has 3999GB. It should give you: "Disk /dev/sd?: 3999 GB, ..." at some point. Where ? will be replaced by a letter a to z ...

If the Disk contains a GPT table it will give you a note and you should use gdisk to edit the table if not try "sudo fdisk /dev/sd?" (replace ? by the letter"

ATTENTION: Using these tools may/will delete EVERYTHING on your disk immediatly!

Comment: Disk /dev/sdc: 4000.0 GB, 3999977701376 bytes 90 heads, 3 sectors/track, 28935023 cylinders, total 7812456448 sectors Units = sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes Disk identifier: 0x2c960c55 Device Boot Start End Blocks Id System /dev/sdc1 2048 4294967294 2147482623+ 83 Linux –

Comment: Well: There you go ..

 /dev/sdc1 2048 4294967294 2147482623

Your Partition starts at the middle of the sdc drive. You may have to extend that to start at the lowest point instead of 4294967294.

So if you will delete sdc1 and create a new sdc1 with the complete size you will have 4TB avaiable.

Comment: ok thank you how do i change the starting point to make it at the beginning and run to the end?  i know when i partitioned the drive i used the recommended start and stop locations.

Comment: im sorry i am a newbe at linux.  the command lines would be a great help

Comment: Just added the stuff to the answer. That should lead you throught the steps.

Comment: @Larry: As you're a reputation 6 user: If this answer helped you, don't forget to click the grey **☑** at the left of this text, which means [Yes, this answer is valid](http://askubuntu.com/help/accepted-answer)!  **;-)**  Oh, and if **one of the disks fails, you lose everything!** So [Backup, please!](http://askubuntu.com/questions/569679/whats-a-good-back-up-strategy-for-1-desktop-pc)

Comment: Did it work out? Or do you still have some problems getting the whole size assigned?

Answer (score 0):

The issue is with your disk layout. From the `fdisk -l`,

Total sectors = `7812456448`
Used Sectors = `4294967294 - 2048 = 4294965246`
Free Sectors = `Total sectors - Used Sectors`

To extend and use all sectors:

Follow this nice answer [How to resize partition](https://askubuntu.com/questions/115310/how-to-resize-enlarge-grow-a-non-lvm-ext4-partition)